# Conditional posterior distribution of coefficient in logistic regression

Tags: bayesian, logistic, spatial, hierarchical-bayesian, conditional-random-field

I would like to derive the conditional distribution of β in a logistic regression where

- Y follows a Binomial distribution B(n,p)
- the probability model is given as: logit(p)=X'β +u+v  ;
- u is spatial random effects and v is non spatial random effects
- β follows a priori a normal distribution

The posterior distribution is given as:

[image: formula]

My question is,  what do I have to replace by

[image: likelihood]

if I want to derive the conditional distribution of β  ?

Is it possible to get the mean and variance of  logit(p)=X' β +u+v so that I can transform it by normal distribution.

Comment: You should write the posterior $f(\beta,u,v,\kappa,\lambda|\mathbf y)$ in terms of the $\beta_j$'s as well, rather than writing $p_i$'s for the likelihood part.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the question is unclear, as well as the background of the OP in terms of exposure to Bayesian statistics.

If considering the full posterior $f(\beta|\mathbf y,\mathbf u,\mathbf v)$, which is given by (up to a multiplicative constant)
$$\prod_{i=1}^n p_i(\beta,\mathbf u,\mathbf v)^{y_i}[1-p_i(\beta,\mathbf u,\mathbf v)]^{n_i-y_i}\varphi(\beta)$$
where $\varphi(\beta)$ denotes the multivariate Normal density. This means that the full posterior is the same as in the regular logistic regression when treating $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ as constant. This is a standard model treated in Bayesian textbooks (as for instance in our [Bayesian Essentials](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO), Section 4.4, pp.124-6). This posterior is not a standard distribution and requires simulation tools to approximate it, incl. its posterior mean and posterior variance. (Once again, this is processed in textbooks like [ours](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO).) It is only asymptotically in $n$ that the posterior turns into a Normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks.  treating u,v as constant.